# Dynamic data in the columns options using ion-picker [Ionic] [Vue]

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuejs3-composition-api

I need help with **ion-picker**.

I'm using **Ionic + Vue** to build an app. The selector that has caught my attention the most is **ion-picker** which is within the following link https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/picker

**Inline Pickers Section (Recommended)​**

The Vue example works perfectly. But I would like to pass the values of **options: []** dynamically from the backend. Which returns the values of "text" and "value" respectively. However, when I do that it shows me a blank picker and it doesn't work 100%.

Documentation data:

```
const pickerColumns = [
   {
      name: 'languages',
      options: [
         {
            text: 'JavaScript',
            value: 'javascript',
         },
         {
            text: 'TypeScript',
            value: 'typescript',
         },
         {
            text: 'Rust',
            value: 'rust',
         },
         {
            text: 'C#',
            value: 'c#',
         },
      ],
   },
];
```

I'm using:

```
Vue 3.
Ionic 7.
Composition API.
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.